# Coordinate-free derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, differential-geometry, xact

Given the function
\begin{align*}
  f \colon \mathbb{R}^n &\to \mathbb{R}^n\\
  v&\mapsto \dfrac{v}{\|v\|},
\end{align*}
I would like to compute the derivative of $f$, that is $df(v)$. It is possible to derive it by hand, which leads to

$$df(v)=\dfrac{1}{\| v\|}\Big(I_n - \dfrac{v}{\|v\|}\otimes \dfrac{v}{\|v\|}\Big)$$

where $I_n$ is the identity second-order matrix.

I believe *Mathematica* cannot find that using simple built-in functions (without explicitly defining `v = {v1, v2, v3}` if $n=3$ for instance).  Some packages are dedicated to differential geometry (see [Coordinate free differential forms package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60243/coordinate-free-differential-forms-package) or [Differential geometry add-ons for Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/differential-geometry-add-ons-for-mathematica)) but I failed to achieve the above calculation. Any hint would be appreciated.

---

**Edit** For those of you who are interesting in how to find the above formula, you can define $g(t)=f(v(t))=\big(v(t)\cdot v(t)\big)^{1/2}v(t)$ and compute $g'(t)$ with the chain rule. $g'(t)$ is a linear function of $v'(t)$ because:

$$g'(t)=\dfrac{df}{dv}(v(t)) v'(t)$$

Taking the coefficient in front of $v'(t)$ gives the above expression.

Now, the naive implementation of this approach as follows fail because it does not capture the multi-dimensionality of the `f`:

```
f[v_] = v/Norm[v]
h[t_] = D[f[v[t]], t]/v'[t] // Simplify
h[t] /. Norm'[v[t]] -> v[t]/Norm[v[t]] // Simplify
(* (Norm[v[t]]^2 - v[t]^2)/Norm[v[t]]^3 *)
```

Comment: What is *I_3*? Can you clarify this?

Comment: @CATrevillian I believe it's `IdentityMatrix[3]`

Comment: @CATrevillian chuy is right, I clarified.

Comment: @anderstood so your `v`, here for instance, is dependent upon `t`, and presumably `v[t]` is an n-dimensional vector? It will be interesting to see what solutions come about from this, as I’d expect somehow to either have to give the dimensionality, or be able to determine it from the inputs.

Comment: @CATrevillian `v` does not necessarily depend on `t` but that's a "trick" I used to derive the expression of $df(v)$ (the trick is to introduce artificially `t` and remove it afterwards). But that's right, `v[t]` would be a vector such as `{v1[t], v2[t], ..., vn[t]}`.

Answer (score 9):

A solution using [FeynCalc](https://feyncalc.github.io/) would be to write

```
ex = CVD[v, i]/Sqrt[CSPD[v, v]]
```

which corresponds to
$
\frac{v^i}{\sqrt{v^2}}
$ (`CVD` denotes a $D-1$ dimensional Cartesian vector, `CSPD` is a Cartesian scalar product in $D-1$ dimensions). Then using the routine `ThreeDivergence` ($\nabla^j$)

```
ThreeDivergence[ex, CVD[v, j]]
```

we find
$
\frac{\delta ^{i j}}{\sqrt{v^2}}-\frac{v^i v^j}{\left(v^2\right)^{3/2}}.
$

Of course, FeynCalc is not a tool for doing differential geometry. The tensor routines only cover what one usually needs in Feynman diagram calculations. So I suppose that for more serious tasks the OP would still need to become familiar with dedicated tensor algebra packages.

Comment: Would you know how to do that with [`xTensor`](http://xact.es/xTensor/) for example?

Comment: Sorry, so far I never needed to use `xTensor`. For what I do for living, `FeynCalc` and `FORM` have always been sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you could use the following approach:

```
Clear[VectorD]

VectorD[e_, v_] := ReplaceAll[
    D[e, VectorD, NonConstants->{v}],
    s_Dot:>TensorReduce[s,Assumptions->v ∈ Vectors[d]]
]

VectorD /: D[s_. v_,VectorD,NonConstants->{v_}] := s IdentityMatrix[d] + 
    TensorProduct[v, D[s, VectorD, NonConstants->{v}]]
VectorD /: D[Transpose[f_], VectorD, NonConstants->{x_}] := Transpose[
    D[f, VectorD, NonConstants->{x}]
]
VectorD /: D[a_Dot|a_Times|a_TensorProduct, VectorD, NonConstants->{x_}] := Sum[
    MapAt[D[#, VectorD, NonConstants->{x}]&, a, i],
    {i,Length[a]}
]
```

Then:

```
VectorD[v/Sqrt[v.v], v]
```

> IdentityMatrix[d]/Sqrt[v.v] - TensorProduct[v, v]/(v.v)^(3/2)

Comment: @anderstood See update

Answer (score 8):

You can abuse the variational derivative functionality in `xTensor` to do this:

```
<< xAct`xTensor`
DefManifold[M, dim, IndexRange[a, m]];
DefMetric[1, metric[-a, -b], PD, PrintAs -> "\[Delta]", 
  FlatMetric -> True, SymbolOfCovD -> {",", "\[PartialD]"}];

DefTensor[v[a], M]
DefScalarFunction[ff]
```

The function `ff` here is a stand-in for "the inverse of the norm".  It has to be typed as a scalar function of some scalar argument(s), so `xTensor` knows how to take its derivative.  (Trying to do this directly using `Sqrt` throws errors;  I'm not sure why.)

```
VarD[v[c], PD][v[a] ff[v[b] v[-b]]] // ScreenDollarIndices // ContractMetric
% /. ff -> (#^(-1/2) &)
```

[image]

Once the variational derivative is taken, you can then set `ff` to any function you please, including (in this case) the -1/2 power function.

Note that the dimensionality of the manifold `dim` remains unspecified in this code.  It might be necessary to specify it in some related cases (for simplification or for calculating traces of quantities), but it doesn't appear to be needed here.